# Why python list changed. I didn't code that

Tags: python-3.x, list

I wonder

```
a = [0] * 3
print(a)
b = [a] * 3
print(b)
b[0][0] = 1
print(b)
```

Why this code's output is

```
[0, 0, 0]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]       
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Why b[1][0] and b[2][0] are also changed?

Comment: Hi :) check this https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747

Comment: Thank you very much!